# How to do load testing in xpages

Tags: testing, xpages

I am facing issue with my xpage application. It works perfectly fine with less number of concurrent users. But When more concurrent users say more then 1000 , try to access xpage application, It becomes very slow. I have looked the code and corrected some redundant code .

But I am not sure this is the issue. For that is there any way in lotus notes to simulate the load testing with 1000 users?

Please help me if any workaround there.

Comment: The cleaner your code is build, the easier your performance testing will be. At the final level you use JMeter, but you have to dig deeper. If your Model (you do MVC?) is well isolated, you can use junit on it to check your bottlenecks there. Also watching memory and CPU as John suggested is important

Answer (score 4):

Agree with Oliver about using JMeter.

But then what you really want is to find out where you have "expensive" code. For an agent you can just "profile" it. However, that is a little less straight-forward for an XPage. You can try the [XPages Toolbox](http://www.openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/XPages%20Toolbox/releases/DAC38BA9929811B986257A1D0069FD64) from OpenNTF.org. I have not tried it on Domino 9.0.x but I would think you could use it.

Another simple (and quick) way to get an idea is to print some time info on the console of the server when you load the pages in your application. You can use a phase listener to add this information - or put it in another more specific location - it really depends on the way that your application is structured. But this way you can get a very quick idea of where the bottlenecks are before you dive into something like the toolbox :-)

/John

Comment: Thanks John. I will try printing time difference in scripts like starting and finishing at important phases, then I will move to Xpages Toolbox and JMeter. I'll come back with the results

Answer (score 2):

We used JMeter to get an idea what will happen if X users will access our app in Y threads etc. http://jmeter.apache.org/